# how do you make content scripts for Chrome extensions based on saved URL's from some data file?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, server

Content scripts usually list the exact URL or a blanket acceptance of certain types of URl's Example below is for every webpage. I want the "matches" to be a data set.
    "manifest_version": 2,

```
"name": "Getting started example",
"description": "This extension shows a Google Image search result for the current page",
"version": "1.0",

"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html "
},
"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
],
"content_scripts": [
    { 
        "matches": ["*://*/*"]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can list the urls you want to use as an array:

```
"content_scripts": [
    { 
        "matches": [
                       "http://www.google.com/*",
                       "http://stackoverflow.com/*"
                   ]
    }
]
```